# Trouble Rendering ApexCharts in Quasar Stepper

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, apexcharts, quasar

I am working with Quasar and the Quasar Stepper component. In my project, I need to render ApexCharts in different steps of the Stepper.

Here's a simplified example of my code on CodePen: [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/mohammad6006/pen/OJrrBor).

In my code, I have two `<div>` elements: one with `id="chart"` in step 1 and another with `id="chart2"` in step 2.

The problem I'm facing is that the chart in the first `<div id="chart">` works as expected, but the chart in the second  doesn't work. I'm not sure why it's not rendering properly in the second step.

I'd appreciate any insights or solutions on how to make the chart in the second step () work as expected within the Quasar Stepper component.

Comment: Add the code in the question as well. So the users can see the code even if the external link expires.